# Change direction of mat-tree angular

Tags: angular

How can I change the direction of a mat-tree-node to "RTL"
and padding-left of node change to right as well?

```html
<mat-tree [dataSource]="dataSource" [treeControl]="treeControl">
    <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node" matTreeNodeToggle matTreeNodePadding>
        <button mat-icon-button disabled></button>
        <mat-checkbox class="checklist-leaf-node" [checked]="checklistSelection.isSelected(node)" (change)="todoLeafItemSelectionToggle(node)">{{node.item}}</mat-checkbox>
    </mat-tree-node>
    <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: hasChild" matTreeNodePadding>
        <button mat-icon-button matTreeNodeToggle [attr.aria-label]="'toggle ' + node.filename">
            <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror">
                {{treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
            </mat-icon>
        </button>
        <mat-checkbox [checked]="descendantsAllSelected(node)" [indeterminate]="descendantsPartiallySelected(node)" (change)="todoItemSelectionToggle(node)">{{node.item}}</mat-checkbox>
    </mat-tree-node>
</mat-tree>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use dir:rl in ur Style

```html
  <mat-tree [dataSource]="dataSource" [treeControl]="treeControl" dir="rtl">
```

Comment: that was easier than I thought!